# Reading web part properties using JavaScript Object Model in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, client-object-model, web-part-property

I am using the below code to read the properties of a web-part using JSOM. While i can read the properties of the web-parts that are there on the current web part page, I would like to know of a way that would allow me to do this without looping through all the web-parts on that page. The looping happens in the code section starting with

> `while (webParts1.moveNext()){...}`

```
function init() {
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
  var pageFile = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/SitePages/TestWebProp.aspx');
  var limitedwpMangager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared)
  var webParts = limitedwpMangager.get_webParts();
  ctx.load(webParts);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var webParts1 = webParts.getEnumerator();
    while (webParts1.moveNext()) {
      var webpart = webParts1.get_current();
      var prop = webpart.get_webPart().get_properties();
      ctx.load(prop);
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        console.log(prop.get_item('Title'));
      },CommonError)
    }
  },CommonError)
}
function CommonError(){
    console.log("Something went wrong");
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init, 'sp.js')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend the following example for loading web parts using JSOM:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var pageFile = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageName);
var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartDefs = webPartManager.get_webParts();
ctx.load(webPartDefs,'Include(WebPart)');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function () {
    for(var i = 0;i < webPartDefs.get_count();i++) {
       var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(i);
       var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
       console.log(webPart.get_title());
    }
  },
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

**Key points**:

- only a **single** request is submitted to the server to retrieve Web
  Parts ( see line `ctx.load(webPartDefs,'Include(WebPart)');`)
- instead of getting Web part Title via properties, it is retrieved via [SP.WebParts.WebPart.title property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247092.aspx)

In order to retrieve *a specific* web part on page you could consider the following methods:

- [SP.WebParts.WebPartDefinitionCollection.getById Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246350.aspx) - returns
  the Web Part definition object in the collection with a Web Part
  identifier equal to the id parameter
- [SP.WebParts.WebPartDefinitionCollection.getByControlId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245374.aspx) - returns
  the Web Part definition object in the collection with a Web Part
  identifier equal to the controlId parameter

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve web part with **properties** by its Id:

> Note: to load [SP.WebParts.WebPart.properties property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247072.aspx) it has to be
>   specified explicitly

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var pageFile = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageName);
var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartDef = webPartManager.get_webParts().getById(webPartid);
var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
ctx.load(webPart,'Properties');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function () {
    var properties = webPart.get_properties();
    console.log(properties.get_fieldValues()['Title']);
  },
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

Comment: Ok. The getById works exactly the way i want it to. But now i am facing another problem. I looked at the DOM and i can see a DIV that looks like `<div id="WebPartctl00_ctl35_g_a70dc106_4ee6_4a5d_9d85_95a2aabcffb1" webpartid2="a70dc106-4ee6-4a5d-9d85-95a2aabcffb1" webpartid="5f8931ff-a930-4942-be06-0fe948ad8c4c">`. How do i know my web part id before hand? Also, There are 2 parameters here webpartid2 and webpartid. Though webpartid works, i would like to know what webpartid2 is.

Comment: This is a different question and i suggest you to post a separate question for that.

Comment: Sure thanks for thanks for the help. Follow up question is [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131724/how-to-get-web-part-id)